# Implementing qgis shortest path feature in map

Tags: qgis, route, shortest-path, qgis-web-client

I have drawn routes on my map in QGIS tool and I checked in using QGIS shortest path tool. I imported the map with the help of qgis2web plugin but when I open the map it has no option for the routes I created between different places. I checked the code and it has a GeoJSON file with all the coordinates of the places.

I want to add to fields "FROM" & "TO" where user can type place names in these fields and it draws a route similar to Google Maps.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid qgis2web does not do any routing at all. You should use the Leaflet code generated by the plugin, and then edit the code to add in one of the Leaflet routing plugins:

http://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#routing

I don't have experience working with any of them, so I can't recommend one, I'm afraid.